# Download embedded vimeo videos with python but without selenium

Tags: python, download, vimeo

I found a great instruction (https://viddownmadness.com/how-to-download-embedded-vimeo-videos/) how to download embedded vimeo videos and thought it would be a nice project to do this in python.

My first idea was to do this in selenium, but maybe you can point me out a more elegant way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step to take is to check if someone did not make it already to avoid so-called *reinventing the wheel*. [Python Package Index](https://pypi.org/) is often good place to start, I searched for [vimeo](https://pypi.org/search/?q=vimeo) and there are many options providing download feature, but I suggest taking [vimeo-downloader](https://pypi.org/project/vimeo-downloader/) as it was updated recently (*Jun 9, 2021*) and packages not updated for long time might not longer work correctly if `vimeo` changed something in meantime. After reading `vimeo-downloader` *Project description* you should be able to install and use it.

Comment: I tested the package with the outcome that the packe only supports vimeo urls or embedded videos if you also provide the internal video.com url. But still thanks for the hint with pypi, I only checked github (and found the same package)